# Different appearance of \dots, \ldots in text and math mode in LuaLaTex + unicode-math (bug)?

Tags: luatex, unicode-math

I get tons of warnings "`Command \textellipsis invalid in math mode`" after I have switched to LuaLaTex. The warning comes from the `unicode-math` package, which I needed to set the math font. If I use `\dots` or `\ldots` (`\vdots` is ok) in math mode, the appearance is different from the text-mode version and I get a warning. If I use PDFLaTex or don't use `unicode-math` there is no difference in appearance and I get no warning.

Is this a bug (or at least is something not correctly implemented)? The MWE illustrates the problem:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{luainputenc}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
Warning: $\dots$\\
Warning: $\ldots$\\
Warning: $\ldots$\\
OK: \dots\\
OK: \ldots\\
OK: $\vdots$
\end{document}
```

LuaLaTex output with unicode-math:

[image]

PDFLaTex output:

[image]

Comment: Remove the call to `luainputenc` to begin with. Isn't it black magic? `;-)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `luainputenc` package should be loaded only with legacy documents, but never when the encoding is already UTF-8.

The package loads `lutf8.def` that has

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2026}{\textellipsis}
```

(which is an error, in my opinion, but it's another matter).

Comment: Congrats on passing the 250K mark!!

Comment: @Mico Halfway to 500K. ;-)

Comment: @egreg: I have read that I need luainputenc but you are right, everything works like a charm even without this package! Thanks, but \dots and \ldots are still different in math and text mode if I use unicode-math. Maybe this is a "feature" although I have to say that I don't like it... ;)

Comment: @user4811 Yes, it's a feature, I'm afraid. Tell who said you to use `luainputenc` that they're wrong.

Comment: In case it's helpful to anyone, I issued \usepackage{ellipsis} to revert the effect of the line that egreg quoted --- I also disagree with the "feature".